# Any existing java library to delete , edit , add certain line in a file with swing in Jmenu?

Tags: java, swing

I am now using Fileutils to access a file to retrieve lines of phone number.

But now I need to add phone number , delete phone number and edit phone number in the file. I do know how to do it with JMenu , but i keep wondering , do anyone create a library for this?

Comment: I don't understand why you would use *JMenu* to modify a text file? JMenu is Swing container to display a menu in a Swing JFrame (window). What on earth has this to do with manipulating text files?

Comment: hmmm .... ya ... i should use a create 2 jpanel and when clicked will switch between the main jpanel and the phone number jpanel , right! thanks for the head  up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to go for DB .

FILE IO in such case is very ugly coding.

and then also if you want to do it.

to modify content you need to create other file read from older and modify it in memory and write it back to new file.

Comment: I avoid DB because i tried to link DB with hibernate but somehow fail ..... hmm , will consider use db ..... It seems that store it in file require more work ... thanks for the head up!

Comment: Yes go for DB, if you fail let us know :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to go for DB, which is the best idea, you should maybe.
Read the whole file and store in a Collection
then, you remove the phone number, and then write it again on file overwriting.
It's definitely much more work. But it works too.
Reminding that the class of the ObjectType needs to implements Serializible.